# Build a shifted signal samples from the original samples

Tags: sampling, signal-synthesis

I have the original samples $\{x_1(nT)\}_{n=1}^N$ of a signal $x_1(t)$, where $T=\frac1{f_\mathrm{s}}$ is the sampling period. I want to find the samples $\{x_2(nT)\}_{n=1}^N$ of the signal $x_2(t)=x_1(t-\tau)$ from these samples. I used the sinc interpolation like this

$$x_1(t-\tau)=\sum_{m=1}^Nx_1(mT)\text{ sinc}\left(\frac{t-\tau}{T}-m\right)$$

So, the samples of the shifted signal are

$$x_2(nT_s)=x_1(nT_s-\tau)=\sum_{m=1}^Nx_1(mT)\text{ sinc}\left(n-m-\frac{\tau}{T}\right)$$

When I plot the two samples $\{x_1(nT)\}$ and $\{x_2(nT)\}$, they are shifted in the time domain, but the time shift doesn't equal $\tau$. Why?

Comment: Is $\tau$ an integer factor?

Comment: No, it can be any random real number

Comment: It would help to show your code and the results. Could be a coding error.  For starters you have aliasing. Since the sequence is finite, it's bandwidth is unlimited. How much aliasing you get depends on the signal.

Comment: @Hilmar Why is there aliasing? and how does this affect the interpolation process? Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: According to the sampling theorem you can only sample without aliasing if the signal is bandlimited. A finite signal is NOT bandlimited and hence cannot be sampled without aliasing. Whether that affects the interpolation really depends on the spectrum of the signal and the sample rate

Comment: @Hilmar somehow the OP has $x_1(t)$ stored in memory already.  It must also be sampled and then those samples are ***presumed*** to be from sufficiently bandlimited material that also has zero samples for $mT\le 0$ and $mT>NT$.

Comment: From the problem definition, if $$x(t)=\sum_{n=1}^N x(nT)\operatorname{ sinc}\left(\frac{t}{T}-n\right)$$ then that ***must*** imply that $$x(nT)=0 \qquad \forall n\in \mathbb{Z} \le 0$$ and $$x(nT)=0 \qquad \forall n\in \mathbb{Z} > N $$  Those samples are ***presumed*** to be from a properly bandlimited function that is explicitly shown above.  But even for $t<0$ or $t>NT$, ***in between*** samples, $x(t) \ne 0$ unless all $N$ samples of $x(nT)=0$ for $1\le n \le N$.

Answer (score -1):

The shifting that you have described in the question is incorrect. You are trying to obtain $x_2[n] = x_1[n - \tau]$ where $\tau \in \mathbb{R}$. The correct way to go about this is to consider a discrete-time system with frequency response:

$$ H(e^{j\omega}) = e^{-j\omega\tau}  \qquad\qquad \quad |\omega| < \pi$$

However, when $\tau \notin \mathbb{Z}$ this frequency response is meaningless since discrete-time signals cannot be shifted by a non-integer amount. So the correct way to approach this is to first convert the signal back to the continuous domain and pass it through a system with this frequency response:

$$ H(j\Omega) = H(e^{j\Omega T_s}) =  e^{-j\Omega T_s\tau}$$

which will then be realized as  such, $x_2(t) = x_1(t - T_s\tau)$. Then we can sample $x_2(t)$ to get our desired signal in the discrete-domain using the following steps:

\begin{align*}
   x_2[n] &= x_2(nT_s) = x_1(nT_s − T_s \tau)\\
    & = \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} x_1[m]\: \mathrm{sinc}[(t-T_s\tau - mT_s)/T_s] \rvert_{t=nT_s}\\
    & = \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} x_1[m] \: \mathrm{sinc}[n- m - \tau]
\end{align*}

which is obviously the convolution of $x_1[n]$ with $\mathrm{sinc}[n-\tau]$ and not $\mathrm{sinc}[n-\frac{\tau}{T_s}]$ as you have described.

Comment: Are you saying we can't shift a signal in a fraction of a sample time? The time shift can be expressed as $\tau=LT_s+\epsilon T_s$ where $L\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $\epsilon\in[0,\,1)$. The term $\epsilon T_s$ is obviously a fraction of $T_s$

Comment: No, what I am saying is that $\tau$ can be anything. But when you implement it be careful and make sure the math behind it is rigorous...

Comment: Down arrow from me.